# Oracle/SQL user defined function equivalent in Couchbase

Tags: oracle, function, couchbase, sql++

In Oracle/SQL we have provision to write user defined functions where we can write complex logic to computer some values and then return back in query.

Do we have such feature in Couchbase?

We are moving from a heavy Oracle database to Couchbase and in existing Oracle database we have a lot stored procedures and user defined functions. So I am confused how to move that entire logic into Couchbase. I had a little about eventing functions but that is for eventing purpose only I guess.

I know we have views in Couchbase, what about user defined functions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

N1QL and javascript functions are in developer preview mode in the upcoming 6.5 release:

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/userfun.html

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve same behaviour in 6.0 or earlier release ?

Comment: The best I can think of is you could have eventing functions that you trigger by touching dummy documents on the kv. Not ideal really.

Comment: Note there are two versions of N1QL JavaScript functions in the 6.5 DP the first are simple inline functions (more pure math no intermediate variables) and the second is more complex external functions (variables are allowed) you can refer to a couchbase forum post for details:

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/do-we-have-stored-procedure-in-couchbase-i-dont-want-to-write-n1ql-inline-query-in-my-code/22871/8

Answer (score 0):

Just touching base on this again...

As [Marco Greco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11692231/marco-greco) noted Eventing is a "special" user defined function that responds to all mutations (inset/upsert or deletes) and allows you to can write complex logic to compute things and update the mutating document (or other documents) or contact a REST API.  To lean more about Eventing refer to [eventing-overview](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-overview.html) and the Eventing [examples](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-examples.html)

Now of course since you said you were interested in a UDF that can return back in query as in N1QL this would be User Defined Functions (UDFs). However that is a currently in a Developer Preview Mode (not to be used for production) for more details see: [n1ql-language-reference/userfun](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/userfun.html).

As I previously mentioned there two versions of N1QL JavaScript functions in the 6.5 DP the first are simple inline functions (more pure math no intermediate variables) and the second is more complex external functions (variables are allowed) refer [forums.couchbase.com/t/do-we-have-stored-procedure...](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/do-we-have-stored-procedure-in-couchbase-i-dont-want-to-write-n1ql-inline-query-in-my-code/22871/8)